# Polar Heart rate sensor not available as data source in google fit api (xamarin android)

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, google-fit

The [google fit api documentation states that](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/ble-sensors)

> If the BLE device is claimed successfully, you can access it like any other sensor using the Recording API and the Sensors API. For example, you can obtain a data source object for the BLE device with the SensorsClient.findDataSources method.

But I am not able to find the datasource which has Polar H10 Sensor as the source. All I am able to find, is the data source of the phone on which I am debugging my application.

Does anybody know how to register a listener to a proper data source using Google Fit Sensors API after a ble device wearable like heart rate sensor has been claimed successfully?

Below is my code of claiming the ble sensor (Polar H10) in C# using Xamarin:

```
 var pending_result = await FitnessClass.BleApi.ClaimBleDeviceAsync(mClient, device);
 if (pending_result.IsSuccess)
 {
    mActivity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {
        releaseButton.Enabled = true;
    });
    FindFitnessDataSources();
  }
```

Below is my code which I use to find a datasource for heartrate_bpm:

```
private async void FindFitnessDataSources()
{
    var dataSourcesResult = await FitnessClass.SensorsApi.FindDataSourcesAsync(mClient, new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
           .SetDataTypes(Android.Gms.Fitness.Data.DataType.TypeHeartRateBpm)
           .SetDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TypeRaw)
           .Build());        

    Console.WriteLine("Result: " + dataSourcesResult.Status);
    foreach (DataSource dataSource in dataSourcesResult.DataSources)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Data source found: " + dataSource.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Data Source type: " + dataSource.DataType);

        ////Let's register a listener to receive Activity data!
        if (dataSource.DataType == Android.Gms.Fitness.Data.DataType.TypeHeartRateBpm)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Registering Listener for " + dataSource.Name);
            RegisterFitnessDataListener(dataSource, Android.Gms.Fitness.Data.DataType.TypeHeartRateBpm);
        }                               
    }
}
```

Below is my code for registering a listener to the datasource found above:

```
private async void RegisterFitnessDataListener(DataSource dataSource, Android.Gms.Fitness.Data.DataType dataType)
{
    mListener = new OnDataPointListener();
    var status = await FitnessClass.SensorsApi.AddAsync(mClient, new SensorRequest.Builder()
          .SetDataSource(dataSource) // Optional but recommended for custom data sets.
          .SetDataType(dataType) // Can't be omitted.
          .SetSamplingRate(1, TimeUnit.Seconds)
          .Build(),
           mListener);


    if (status.IsSuccess)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Listener registered!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Listener not registered.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that the SensorsApi only allows you to access devices that run on WearOS. And to my knowledge the Polar watches except the M600 run on a different device. I'm currently having the same issue with a Samsung Galaxy Watch. I think the only way is to sync data via the Polar app to the Google Fit app and then requesting the history data of the Google Fit app.
If you find any way to get this working via the SensorsAPI please let me know, because i also try to make it work!